# how can i get this element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm looking for answer about this code

```
getFilesByRepo(e) {
  console.log(e.target.innerText)

  this.axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/********/${e.target.innerText}/contents`)
    .then((result) => {
      result.data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.name)
        e.append(`<h1>${element.name}</h1>`)
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });

},
```

about  --> `e.append` <-- this section, how can I get this `e`'s element??

to use only vanila.js please

Comment: What do you mean _"how"_? It's the function parameter. You already have it.

Comment: Because of `e.target` and the name I would guess that `e` is an `Event` object. If that's the case then there's no `.append()` method. Do you want `e.target.append(...)`?

Comment: i can resolved that e.append => e.target.append  hhhh
thank you and have a nice day!